# Ender dragon does not respawn in realms

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

When playing Minecraft realms with a couple friends we defeated the Ender Dragon, and I want to spawn him in again. When I place the four end crystals at the exit portal it doesn't do anything and the crystals sit there without activating the respawn animation. I am playing in 1.10.

Answer (score 5):

You have encountered a known bug in 1.10, [MC-103497](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-103497), in which the ender dragon does not respawn due to the game failing to save some data between sessions. It was fixed in 1.10.1.

This bug occurs mostly on realms, presumably because realms sort of hibernate when no one is playing. To prevent the bug, someone would need to enter the end every time anyone is playing.

Comment: A temporary workaround to spawn Enderdragon in survival is to use same method as [one used to spawn Enderdragon with only two crystals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTkVWpG6V2I). Make sure that you read bug report and know implications of using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to respawn it and you are able try doing this if you have access to the /summon commad:

> The /summon EnderDragon command, by default, summons a
> harmless ender dragon that hovers in place. Setting the DragonPhase
> tag, for instance by issuing /summon EnderDragon ~ ~ ~
> {DragonPhase:0}, will create a normal ender dragon, though with no
> health bar since the bar is managed by the End's dragon fight status
> rather than by the dragon entity itself.

This is from https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Dragon